# Does sequence matter in case of pam_env.so and pam_tally2.so together?

Tags: pam

Very short question.

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=3 even_deny_root unlock_time=120
```

or

```
auth        required      pam_tally2.so deny=3 even_deny_root unlock_time=120
auth        required      pam_env.so
```

Does the sequence matter in this case? If it does then why?

#### Edit1

To make it clear - `pam_tally2.so` possibly does not user environment variables `pam_env.so` could filter out, so the answer to this question is probably "the sequence does not matter". The main question should rather be - if I wrote my own pam module, would I have environment changed if pam_env.so was listed before me?